# Content moves to left side when 'tab' key is pressed

Tags: html, css

I was creating something more complex than the code snippet bellow, until I encountered a bug.
If you click on the textfield, then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the textfield and its' siblings move way over to the left side.

What is causing this, and how can I stop it from happening?

(The reason there are so many unnecessary `divs`, is because as I said before, this is from a much more complex project. I narrowed it down to the following.)

#### JSFiddle

```html
<div id="fullWrapper" style="width: 470px;">
  <div id="pickerWrapper" style="width: 470px;">
    <div id="overallSlidersWrapper" style="position: relative; background-color: greenYellow;">
      <div class="sliderOuterWrapper" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="sliderInnerWrapper" style="width: 940px; display: flex;">
          <div class="sliderInnerContentWrapper" style="overflow: hidden; width: 470px;">
            <div class="sliderContent">
              <input type="text">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nYp8cnV.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sliderInnerContentWrapper" style="overflow: hidden; width: 0px;">
            <div class="sliderContent">
              <input type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're tabbing to the next element: the image.

If you hit SHIFT-TAB (reverse tab function in Windows), you'll end up back in the input.

The effect is caused by child elements being larger than their containers. If you switch the overflowing elements from `width: 940px` to `width: 100%`, the shifting effect is removed.

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nwt4n5n3/2/)

---

### `tabindex`

With the `tabindex` attribute you can control the tabbing order.

- Elements with a positive value are navigated first, in chronological order
- Elements that don't support `tabindex` or have a value of 0 tab next, in HTML source order
- Elements with a negative value (e.g. `tabindex="-1"`) cannot receive focus via tabbing

More details here: [7.4.1 Sequential focus navigation and the tabindex attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex)

Comment: Thanks! That explains it! I have to have it at `940px`. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: If you must tab to an image that is 940px wide in a smaller container, then the layout will shift as you've noted in the question.

Comment: I don't have to press tab, but while I was testing out the more complex project, I happened to press tab, then this happened. If a user hits tab, I don't want the content to disappear.
Is there some sort of hack or something to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can control where users can tab with the `tabindex` attribute; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing  `tabindex="-1"` (I tried it on all the `divs`) and it didn't help

Comment: Oh. I didn't do it for the second input. It works now. Do I have to give tabIndex=1` to all sliderContent children, grand children, etc?

Comment: Use `tabindex` on the elements you want chronologically ordered. Elements without `tabindex` will be focused in source order. In other words, you do not need to add `tabindex` to every element. Just the ones you want prioritized for tabbing.

Answer (score 0):

your "sliderInnerWrapper" has a width of 940px whereas it container is 470px. this means the content will scroll inside the container. hitting tab is focusing the next object which causes the scroll accross to show the rest of the "sliderInnerWrapper"'s content.

Comment: a solution depends on what you are trying to achieve. you have a large object within a container that is too small for it. you need to know what size you want then build around that. also you have unnececary repetition of structure, "fullWrapper" and "pickerWrapper" are the same thing so why have one inside the other if its just a repetition of code layers. you could make this much simpler by having a couple of div containers. it would also make it much more simple as you wouldn't have to repeat sizing which leads to mismatch which is what you have.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the question: "(The reason there are so many unnecessary divs, is because as I said before, this is from a much more complex project. I narrowed it down to the following.)"

Comment: in that case you juneed to simplify the sizing. if you want it to be 470px leave the top at 470 and each layer to fill 100%. if you want 940px remove all the 470's and place 940 at the top.

Answer (score 0):

@Jessica put your tabindex="-1" attribute on the second hidden input. This will fix the issue.

```html
<div id="fullWrapper" style="width: 470px;">
    <div id="pickerWrapper" style="width: 470px;">
        <div id="overallSlidersWrapper" style="position: relative; background-color: greenYellow;">
            <div class="sliderOuterWrapper" style="overflow: hidden;">
                <div class="sliderInnerWrapper" style="width: 960px; display: flex;">
                    <div class="sliderInnerContentWrapper" style="overflow: hidden; width: 470px;">
                        <div class="sliderContent">
                            <input type="text">
                            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nYp8cnV.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sliderInnerContentWrapper"  style=" overflow: hidden; width: 0px; ">
                        <div class="sliderContent">
                            <input tabindex="-1" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So I have to give `tabIndex=`1` to all `sliderContent` children, grand children etc?